# Run application in simulator on other machine

Tags: testing, ios-simulator

I'm working on an application and my colleague wants to test the application on simulator on other machine on other location(it's a matter of time until he'll receive a real device to test the application).
It's possible to export the application from my machine and import it on the other.
I don't want to give access to the code - just to run the application to understand the flow and write o document for the customer.

Kind Regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the application in Xcode and then send it over to the other machine (zip file, tarball, whatever).  Once there, you can extract it, boot the sim device you want to install to, and use the simctl command line tool to install it:

```
xcrun simctl install booted /pat/to/your/built.app
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I receive this error : @"No devices are booted."

Comment: Yes.  Boot the device you want to install the app on.